# print out unicode characters in assembly using wprintf linux x86-64 platform

Tags: assembly, unicode, nasm, gnu-assembler

I'm using linux and just experimenting with nasm and gas.  I am able to print out unicode characters using wprintf using c++

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  //printf("helloworld"); // can't do this AND wprintf in same program
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wprintf(L"%lc",0x307E); //prints out japanese hiragana ma ま
}
```

however I'm very much confused at trying to do it in assembly (both intel and gas syntax).My main confusion is with the .data section.  I've even given gcc the -S switch to see how they do it.  They do the format string with 13 .string statements, many of them blank strings and each character on a separate .string. I read that you can essentially make a regular string a wide string in nasm by placing the string in a dw rather than a db.  So of course I tried with .int for gas, but that doesn't work out so well.  By that I mean it prints out extra gray question marks.
here is my current code

```
.section .data
locale:
  .string ""
printformat:
  .int '%','l','c'
printwide:
  .int 0x307E,0
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
movq    $locale,%rsi
movq    $6,%rdi
call    setlocale
movq    $printformat,%rdi
movq    $printwide,%rsi
movq    $0,%rax
call    wprintf
movq    $2,%rdi
call    exit
```

This results in 5 grayed out question marks then the hiragana ま (ma).  You would think that after '%','l','c'  there should be a ,0, but that doesn't work--only question marks are outputted after doing that.
The only way I have been able to just print out the hiragana ma and no question marks is by skipping the format string and just loading printwide into rdi.

Again, this is for educational purposes at the moment.
So basically, how do you do the format string in both at&t syntax and intel?  In c++ you simply put an L in front of it. ( and yes I suppose you could change the %lc into hex, but I don't want to do it like that )

**EDIT**  this works (I changed $printwide to printwide and changed printformat: to .strings like the gcc -S listing did.)  But why does it work and is there a better way to write out the format other than using so many .string statements?  and how would you do it in intel syntax?

```
.section .data
locale:
    .string ""
printformat:
    .string "%"
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string "l"
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string "c"
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
printwide:
    .word 0x307E
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
movq    $locale,%rsi
movq    $6,%rdi
call    setlocale
movq    $printformat,%rdi
movq    printwide,%rsi
movq    $0,%rax
call    wprintf
movq    $2,%rdi
call    exit
```

Comment: Which unicode encoding do you want to use?  UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: I believe I want UTF-8, what was used in my c++ file?

Comment: The C code uses UTF-16 (or similar, depending on the CRTL).  The assembly is creating string constants using `.int` so it is either UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on the size that pseudo-op generates which could well be influenced by assembler command line options or environment variables.

Comment: I've tried .word and .hword too.  Still outputs question marks before and after the ま

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised by the answer.  I guess in 64 bit wide characters are 32-bit.  I found this out by reading up on nasm.  You can make a string utf-16 in intel syntax by the following

```
printformat dw __utf16__("%lc"),0
```

however it only worked when I did

```
printformat dd __utf32__("%lc"),0
```

and so the equivalent in at&t syntax would be

```
.long '%','l','c',0
```

I guess gcc -S 's listing using so many strings makes it 32 bits wide

.string "%" = 16 bits ( the % and the automatic zero ) then another 8 bits with an empty string, then another 8 bits with another empty string.